# Pick elements in one array based on the elements of another array?

Tags: python, numpy, range

I have 2 numpy arrays: array 1 has elements 1 .. 100 denoting ranges to check (the least-significant digit is omitted), array 2 has values 1 .. 1000 to check against each of those ranges.

```
import numpy
o = numpy.array([3, 7, 20, 47, 60, 72, 76, 83, 94, 94])
p = numpy.array([22, 54, 77, 83, 246, 285, 813, 828, 950, 998])
```

The aim is to get the indexes of the elements in array 2 that are within any range of array 1. For instance, for 22 we need to check:

```
30 < 22 < 40 => false
70 < 22 < 80 => false
etc. (all are false, so index 0 will not be in the result)
```

and 77 will be true, since it lies within the exclusive range `<70;80>`

What is the correct syntax?

```
In [238]: o
Out[238]: array([ 3,  7, 20, 47, 60, 72, 76, 83, 94, 94])

In [239]: p
Out[239]: array([ 22,  54,  77,  83, 246, 285, 813, 828, 950, 998])

In [240]: p[o*10 < p < (o+1)*10 ]

 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

This seems to work but is very complicated:
(absolute subtraction with bottom .. top values with compared value should equal 10)

> e.g. abs(77-60) + abs(77-70) == 10

```
In [329]: oo = numpy.vstack(((o*10), (o+1)*10 ) )

In [324]: ten = numpy.abs(numpy.subtract(oo[0,:],p.reshape(-1,1))) + numpy.abs(numpy.subtract(oo[1,:],p.reshape(-1,1)))

array([[  26,  106,  366,  906, 1166, 1406, 1486, 1626, 1846, 1846],
       [  38,   42,  302,  842, 1102, 1342, 1422, 1562, 1782, 1782],
       [  84,   10,  256,  796, 1056, 1296, 1376, 1516, 1736, 1736],
       [  96,   16,  244,  784, 1044, 1284, 1364, 1504, 1724, 1724],
       [ 422,  342,   82,  458,  718,  958, 1038, 1178, 1398, 1398],
       [ 500,  420,  160,  380,  640,  880,  960, 1100, 1320, 1320],
       [1556, 1476, 1216,  676,  416,  176,   96,   44,  264,  264],
       [1586, 1506, 1246,  706,  446,  206,  126,   14,  234,  234],
       [1830, 1750, 1490,  950,  690,  450,  370,  230,   10,   10],
       [1926, 1846, 1586, 1046,  786,  546,  466,  326,  106,  106]])

In [330]: numpy.where(ten == 10)
Out[330]: (array([2, 8, 8]), array([1, 8, 9]))

In [331]: p[ numpy.where(ten == 10)[0] ]
Out[331]: array([ 77, 950, 950])
```

Comment: o contains 94 twice. What is the point of checking that range twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intersection of two masks as follows. However, in your example their intersection appears to be empty:

```
x = p[(o*10 < p) & (p < (o+1)*10)]
```

Comment: 7 => 70 - 80 i.e. 77 should be OK

Comment: Well but the 7 is at position 2 in `o`, while 77 is at position 3 in `p`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use `any` and `map` to do the real work, not `where`, which does some magic to determine what to iterate over, and fails when there is more than one iterable in your expression.

```
>>> numpy.where( map( lambda pval : numpy.any( (o*10 < pval) & (pval < (o+1)*10) ), p) )
(array([2]),)
```

## long answer

Comparing an array gives an array of results. For the moment, take only a single range check to be applied:

```
>>> o*10 < 77
array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

@ypnos correctly notes how this can be combined with another comparison:

```
>>> (o*10 < 77) & (77 < (o+1)*10)
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

This performs an AND operation on each element of the lists pairwise (and as you can see, 77 lies in the range of the second element of o, 7, which denotes `70 < 77 < 80`. However, we are not interested in which comparison, only that one of them succeeded, so let's collapse the result with `any()`:

```
>>> numpy.any( (o*10 < 77) & (77 < (o+1)*10) )
True
>>> numpy.any( (o*10 < 22) & (22 < (o+1)*10) )
False
```

The conundrum is how to then apply that operation to each element of p, rather than only checking 22 as above. The [documentation for numpy.where](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) doesn't explain how an array is selected from the conditional given, but even wrapping our existing condition in a function and just calling that as a conditional on a single variable still does not work:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     return numpy.any( (o*10 < x) & (x < (o+1)*10) )
...
>>> numpy.where( foo(p) )
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

In this case, we actually need `map`, not `where`, which takes a predicate and an iterable and applies the predicate (boolean function) to the iterable (numpy array result from our previous comparisons and any() call). The result becomes:

```
>>> map(foo,p)
[False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Or directly, using a lambda instead of foo function:

```
>>> map( lambda pval : numpy.any( (o*10 < pval) & (pval < (o+1)*10) ), p)
[False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

You then want the indices, so apply where to that:

```
>>> numpy.where( map( lambda pval : numpy.any( (o*10 < pval) & (pval < (o+1)*10) ), p) )
(array([2]),)
```